# Incorrect loop result

Tags: c#, arrays, list, loops

First array is filled randomly, its length is set from the console .I have an array in which I need to write a sub-array of repeating numbers and the number of repeating numbers. For example {3 3 3 3 3 4}, 3 3 3 3 is the repeating numbers, 4 is their number.

The problem is that if there are repeating numbers at the end of the array, the loop doesn't output them and if I enter the debug mode, I can see that not all numbers are written. What could be the problem?

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i - 1] == array[i])
    {
        if((i + 1) != array.Length)
        {
            duplicateCount++;
            addArray = array[i - 1];
            duplicate += addArray + " ";                        
        }
        else
        {
            duplicateCount++;
            lastElement = array[i - 1];
            duplicate += lastElement;
        }                 
    }
    else
    {                    
        if (duplicateCount != 1)
        {
            addPrevious = array[i - 1];
            duplicate += addPrevious + " ";
            duplicateArrays.Add(duplicate + duplicateCount);
            duplicate = "";
            duplicateCount = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            duplicateCount = 1;
        }
    }
}

duplicateArrays.Add(duplicate + duplicateCount);
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, can you clarify what you are asking with an example. I suggest you peruse the SO [tour] section as it shows how SO works. The [ask] section may help. In addition, you may find the SO [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) section useful.

Comment: Its not clear what you are asking, though likely you just need to use a GroupBy

Comment: are you trying to say that from a big random array various sub arrays will be created which will be having repeated numbers from that big random array and also be having the last element containing a number which will signify how many times the previous elements are occurred in the sub array?

Comment: if my understanding is correct about your problem, I've created a code that is doing what you want to do. Please check if that is what you were expecting: https://onlinegdb.com/dD2_LJgnY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the Antidisestablishmentarianism code is the shortest one, it uses '**^**' which is **index from end** operator introduced in **C# 8.0**. I'm not carping about that but it's a difference worth knowing. Compiling the same code in the older version will generate a compile time exception. I'll be giving a long yet beginner friendly code which is pretty self-explanatory if you read it twice.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] RandomArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1, 5, 2, 9, 8, 9, 8, 8, 5, 3, 4, 1 };
    int RandomArrayLength = RandomArray.Length;
    List<int[]> SubArrayList = new List<int[]>();
    List<int> visited = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < RandomArrayLength; i++)
    {
        int elem = RandomArray[i];
        if (!visited.Contains(elem))
        {
            visited.Add(elem);
            List<int> templist = new List<int>();
            for (int j = 0; j < RandomArrayLength; j++)
            {
                if (elem == RandomArray[j])
                {
                    templist.Add(elem);
                }
            }
            if (templist.Count > 1) //You can remove this condition if you want to include all the elements
            {
                int elemCount = templist.Count;
                List<int> sublist = new List<int>();
                sublist.AddRange(templist);
                sublist.Add(elemCount);
                SubArrayList.Add(sublist.ToArray());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
    int SubArrayListCount = SubArrayList.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < SubArrayListCount; i++)
    {
        int[] SubArr = SubArrList[i];
        int SubArrCount = SubArr.Length;
        for (int j = 0; j < SubArrCount; j++)
        {
            Console.Write(SubArr[j].ToString() + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

[image: Output:]